# use options Owl Carousel 2 with vue

Tags: vue.js, owl-carousel

I've used Owl Carousel 2 with Vue.js, I've installed it using npm and it worked but I can't use the options for item Number.

This is my code

```
<carousel :item='2'>
```

It's still on the default number "3"

Comment: Try `<carousel :items='2'>`.

Comment: good job it's work  , now how i can use this code ?
```
<carousel :responsive="{ 0: { items: 1, nav: false }, 600: { items: 3, nav: true }}">
```